# How to print accuracy in each fold of Validation Dataset? and assign fold number to each row in the dataframe?

Tags: gridsearchcv

How to print the accuracy in each fold of a Validation Dataset ? And how can I assign the fold number to each row in the dataframe?

```
classifier = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs = -1, criterion='mse')
clf = GridSearchCV(classifier, param_grid = tunedParameters,cv=10)
all_accuracies = cross_val_score(classifier, X=X_train, y=y_train, cv=10)
print(all_accuracies)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up `GridSearchCV` and `cross_val_score`; you should only need to run one of them.

`GridSearchCV` will search through your hyperparameter space, for each combination using cross-validation and producing a score.  You can access these scores through the attribute `cv_results_`.

`cross_val_score` has no hyperparameter search; it just scores using cross-validation.  The output is a list of the individual fold scores.

If you've already used `GridSearchCV`, there's probably no reason to use `cross_val_score`.  (After hyperparameter searching, you've seen and used all the data in that set, so the scores in `cv_results_` are biased as would be the scores out of `cross_val_score`; if you need an unbiased estimate of performance, you'll need another test set (or nested cross-validation in the first place).)

If you want to keep track of which samples go in which fold, I think you need to use a cross-validation generator or iterable for the `cv` parameter instead of an integer.  Then you can use that generator/iterable to also tell you which samples are in which fold.